# Don't allow negative value from button press

Tags: android

Good afternoon,

I have searched around for this answer, but because I am not exactly sure how to ask it, I am having a hard time finding an answer that fits my needs.  I was working on a golf score card tutorial, which I have completed, however, now I am looking to continue on with the application and make it even better.

Right now for each hole I have a score value with a "+" button and a "-" button, and when you hit that button it either does score--; or score++;

```
case R.id.buttonMinus:
    score--;
    textScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    break;
case R.id.buttonPlus:
    score++;
    textScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    break;
```

What I am wondering is how do I not allow "score" to be less than 0?

I would like users to be able to go up and down, but not less than 0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Rob

Comment: "Good afternoon" close as too localized? <— joke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
case R.id.buttonMinus:
    if (score > 0)
        score--;
    textScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    break;
```

Comment: Thank you so much - It works perfectly!  I will accept answer in 9 minutes :)